# Object is not abstract and does not implement abstract member

Tags: kotlin, serialization

I'm trying to implement a custom serializer using Kotlin's serialization.
When I paste the example code into Android Studio 3.1.3 I get a warning:

```
Object DateSerializer is not abstract and does not implement abstract member
public abstract val serialClassDesc: KSerialClassDesc defined in kotlinx.serialization.KSerializer
```

The code I am using is:

```
import kotlinx.serialization.*
import kotlinx.serialization.json.JSON
import java.text.DateFormat
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat
import java.util.*

@Serializer(forClass = Date::class)
object DateSerializer : KSerializer<Date> {
    private val df: DateFormat = SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss.SSS")

    override fun save(output: KOutput, obj: Date) {
        output.writeStringValue(df.format(obj))
    }

    override fun load(input: KInput): Date {
        return df.parse(input.readStringValue())
    }
}
```

Example source: [https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.serialization/example-jvm/src/WithDemo.kt](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.serialization/blob/e009c130082e19669725ceb4bb5211b6711291f2/example-jvm/src/WithDemo.kt)

I assume the example is correct - what am I doing wrong?

Comment: I recommend you avoid the `SimpleDateFormat` class. It is not only long outdated, it is also notoriously troublesome. Today we have so much better in [`java.time`, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/). Also for serialization why not stick to [ISO 8601 format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601)? java.time classes read and write this format without the need for any explicit formatters.

Comment: Sounds like good advise :) I didn't do that here because this an example provided by Kotlin.Serialization. I fixed the warning and have added it here because I couldn't find the answer on StackOverflow or by Googling.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The warning is saying that the DateSerializer object needs (and does not contain) the `val serialClassDesc: KSerialClassDesc` which is present in the object it is overriding.

Add it in to remove the warning (the SerialClassDescImpl property "Date" is the name of the object you are serializing - I believe it can be any string)

```
import kotlinx.serialization.*
import kotlinx.serialization.json.JSON
import kotlinx.serialization.internal.SerialClassDescImpl
import java.text.DateFormat
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat
import java.util.*

@Serializer(forClass = Date::class)
object DateSerializer : KSerializer<Date> {
    private val df: DateFormat = SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss.SSS")

    override fun save(output: KOutput, obj: Date) {
        output.writeStringValue(df.format(obj))
    }

    override fun load(input: KInput): Date {
        return df.parse(input.readStringValue())
    }
    override val serialClassDesc: KSerialClassDesc = SerialClassDescImpl("Date")
}
```